# Where to find probability density plots for all elements?

Tags: soft-question, specific-reference, atoms, atomic-physics

Does anyone know where I can find something [similar to this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aHydrogen_Density_Plots.png), but for all elements?

I would love to find something with the same image quality.

Also, is there any software that can produce images like these?

Comment: For all elements except the Hydrogen, the relevant "wave" isn't just a wave in 3D. It's a wave in 3Z dimensions where Z is the number of electrons. One can calculate the average charge density in 3D but this is a brutal reduction of the information stored in the wave function - the latter knows about all the mutual correlations in the positions and velocities in individual electrons, too. And chemistry depends on these correlations. So 3D pictures (or even 2D pictures) of more complicated atoms than hydrogen are just childish caricatures, not really relevant for the dynamics in physics.

Comment: See my answer to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51660/do-electrons-in-multi-electron-atoms-really-have-definite-angular-momenta/51678#51678: multi-electron atoms don't have discrete electron orbitals. If you calculate the total electron density of whole atoms (I had to do this as an undergrad project) it is almost spherically symmetric. "Almost" in this context means that to the eye the plots of electron density look spherical.

Comment: @John: but aren't some of the hydrogen configurations in the this diagram "multi-electron"? The diagram above is so symmetrical and easy to understand, the perfect arrangement of electrons that repel each other yet are attracted to the same proton. And the electrons in this diagram seem so discrete that I thought it would be possible to do the same for more complicated atoms.

Comment: *" but aren't some of the hydrogen configurations in the this diagram "multi-electron"?"* No. Those are all single electron state. And, yes, some of them *do* have regions of very low density (it actually *does* to to zero in a few places) between regions of high density. This is quantum mechanics, and you have to get over imaging that there is a classic analogy. These figures should help with that.